# Equation with four bessel functions and a parameter

Tags: logarithms, parametric, bessel-functions

If $a$ is a parameter how can I solve this equation:$$\left(\frac {x\left(J_{\frac 34}(\frac {x^2}{2})-J_{-\frac 54}(\frac {x^2}{2})\right)}{2J_a(\frac {x^2}{2})}-\frac{1}{2x}\right)^2-\ln \left(\left(
\frac{xJ_a(\frac{x^2}{2})}{2}\right)\right)^2=x^2$$
???

Comment: Do you intend "$(\ln ( \dots) )^2$" or "$\ln( ( \dots)^2)$".  (This is a common enough error...)

Comment: $$\ln((...))^2$$Thanks fo the clarification.